# Why does the search not consider word-parts?

Tags: bug, search

For example, when trying to dig up [an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12702103/500104), I had to resort to my browser history, because [the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2b%2b%5D%20%5Bc%2b%2b11%5D%20has_trivial*) wouldn't show it to me, no matter what.

The same goes for tries to find it with `user:me is:answer trivial` and similar queries. Can we get the search fixed to find stuff like that? Or can somebody explain me how I can (correctly) search for wildcards?

Comment: [This Google query](https://www.google.com.sg/#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+trivial+%22answered%22+Xeo) narrows it down to the second page :)

Answer (score 2):

Wildcard searches such as the one you linked are in fact supported now.  This is a side-effect of an earlier improvement but useful all around, enjoy!

For those curious, the search was `[c++] [c++11] has_trivial*`

Comment: Awesome! Have a banana: 